# Enable Internet Access to few ips only during a specific time in squid

Tags: linux, squid

Greetings...

I am new to squid and i had configured it in my organization successfully.

Now i want to enable Internet Access to few ips only during a specific time ie. 1.00 PM to 2.00 PM and 6.00PM  to 7.00 PM.

Please let me know how to do it.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This page explains how to block during certain times of the week and day:

http://martybugs.net/smoothwall/squid.cgi

ctrl+f for Time Restrictions: